# In which table does customer data get saved, in particular created_from?

Tags: customer, customer-attribute

I'm wondering where the customer data get saved in Magento. Actually it seems to be pretty clear - in one of the customer_* tables. But I can't find the email_address nor the "created_from" values. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customers password and "created from" are stored in customer_entity_varchar. These are eav attributes.

```
select * from eav_attribute where frontend_label like "Created From";
```